# How to Store multiple 5-element structures from five registers in assembly of armv8/aarch64/arm64?

Tags: assembly, simd, arm64, armv8

Now, I have five 128-bits SIMD register:

```
v0: p0  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7
v1: p8  p9  p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15
v2: p16 p17 p18 p19 p20 p21 p22 p23
v3: p24 p25 p26 p27 p28 p29 p30 p31
v4: p32 p33 p34 p35 p36 p37 p38 p39
```

where pn is the pixel value. I want to store these data to memory, which storage form is "`p0 p8 p16 p24 p32 p1 p9 p17 p25 p33 p2 p10 p18 p26 p34 p3 p11 p19 p27 p35 p4 p12 p20 p28 p36 p5 p13 p21 p29 p37 p6 p14 p22 p30 p38 p7 p15 p23 p31 p39`".

This requirement is similar to [st4](https://developer.arm.com/products/architecture/cpu-architecture/a-profile/docs/ddi0596/latest/simd-and-floating-point-instructions-alphabetic-order/st4-multiple-structures). But there is not have "st5" instruction .

How can I do it? Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: How efficient does this need to be?  Obviously it's easy if performance doesn't matter.  Have you tried doing a transpose in registers, and then doing 8 overlapping unaligned stores?  (So you overwrite the last 3 elements from the previous store).  Overlapping unaligned vector stores are fairly efficient on x86, but IDK if AArch64 microarchitectures are similarly efficient at absorbing them in the store buffer.  And of course the transpose will take several shuffles.

Comment: It's important for the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The **st4** instruction does the job of your use case but since you have 5 registers it won't work for your use case. However, **st4** instruction stores the elements one by one and not one lane of all 4 registers are stored simultaneously. Hence you could rearrange the elements of your choice to be stored and using **str** or **st1** variants for your use case.

Comment: worth noting though that st4 is allowed to be tearing and in most real implementations is probably microcoded to separate stp like instructions. There's not much benefit here in most cases other than, say, instruction cache pressure.